# Error while installing pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip

While installing `pip` via `get-pip.py` faced this error, Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
 C:\Python32>python get-pip.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>

        main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main

        bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)

  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap

        import pip

  File "c:\users\kanika~1\appdata\local\temp\tmps55rv7\pip.zip\pip\__init__.py", 
  line 21, in <module>

  File "c:\users\kanika~1\appdata\local\temp\tmps55rv7\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>

  File "c:\users\kanika~1\appdata\local\temp\tmps55rv7\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 856
    http_error_msg = u'%s Client Error: %s for url: %s' % (self.status_code, reason, self.url)

                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is Python version?